# Get result of array elements which are not matched into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration, javascript-objects

I am new to Javascript. I have the following Mongodb Result Array

```
Result = [
          {
            "userId": "5cecfab4219aca350421b063",
            "providers": [
              "1689736266",
              "1598763690",
              "1528069614",
              "1831364272",
              "1548463045",
              "1245301159",
              "1386616399",
              "1790775971",
              "1629462130",
              "1992169783"
            ],
            "countByType": {
              "doctors": 6,
              "labs": 0,
              "hospitals": 0,
              "imagingCenters": 0,
              "other": 4
            },
            "id": "5cecfab4219aca350421b066"
          }
         ]
```

I have another Array

```
newArray = [1689736266, 1831364272, 123456789, 235695654 ];
```

how to get the array value in newArray which are not in MongoDBResult providers Array.

Eg: anotherArray = [123456789, 235695654];

Also how can I get the providers Array result using Javascript.

Comment: You can use array difference, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: `Result.providers.filter(provider => !newArray.includes(provider))`

Comment: @nickzoum you have to apply the filter on newArray not on providers, but this is the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` on the `newArray` and check if its present in providers array of `Result` using `includes()`

```js
const Result = [ { "userId": "5cecfab4219aca350421b063", "providers": [ "1689736266", "1598763690", "1528069614", "1831364272", "1548463045", "1245301159", "1386616399", "1790775971", "1629462130", "1992169783" ], "countByType": { "doctors": 6, "labs": 0, "hospitals": 0, "imagingCenters": 0, "other": 4 }, "id": "5cecfab4219aca350421b066" } ]
         
const newArray = [1689736266, 1831364272, 123456789, 235695654 ];
const anotherArray = newArray.filter(x => !Result[0].providers.includes(String(x)))

console.log(anotherArray)
```

Comment: Also how to check if anotherArray has some value inside if condition, only if, then execute this block.

Comment: @Vishnu `if(anotherArray.includes(some value)){...}`

Comment: Now I have empty array. So donot execute code if array is empty. How to achive this brother?

Comment: @Vishnu Please update your question and elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()`:

```js
 

const providers =  [
          "1689736266",
          "1598763690",
          "1528069614",
          "1831364272",
          "1548463045",
          "1245301159",
          "1386616399",
          "1790775971",
          "1629462130",
          "1992169783"
        ];

const newArray = [1689736266, 1831364272, 123456789, 235695654 ];

const res = providers.filter(e => !newArray.includes("" + e));
console.log(res);
```